# Tool to automatically apply 'const' to C code

Tags: c, code-analysis

We are planning to make better use of the `const` qualifier in our C code.

To speed this up for our existing codebase, I'm looking for a tool that automatically applies `const` to function parameters that are not modified within the function.

Is there a tool, or a feature within another source analysis tool, that could do this?

Comment: If one does not exist, I might explore making one with https://github.com/eliben/pycparser.

Answer (score 1):

What  you need is a tool that can parse (*real*) C code, compute side effects of functions (and check to see if the parameters are in that list), can modify the parameter lists and regenerate the source code.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=SoftwareRecommendations) can do all of these tasks.  It has [full C front end](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html?Home=FrontEnd), does control and data flow analysis on C which is used to compute side effects, and can apply [source-to-source transformations](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html?Home=DMSToolkit) to change the code where necessary.

OPs solution isn't off the shelf.  Instead one configures DMS to implement that analysis and code changes desired.

Whether this is cost effective will depend on the size of OP's code base.